# Get products that Product Id Not In In Product REST API in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am working on custom APP
I Need to there is any option that we can pass product's into REST API product api into shopify that we did not want that products id's in "admin/api/2022-04/products.json" in this api e.g

We did not want product id 75825896,48589658,4785996 that we can pass these ids into "admin/api/2022-04/products.json" api and did not return these product's ids information

Comment: You want to exclude some products from the Admin API? I'm afraid that is not possible.

Comment: Yes I want exclude some products from admin REST API

Comment: As if it's not possible, if you explain why, we can try to see if there are other solutions.

Comment: I am making partial product process that if product is added into partial list that product needs to be hide from product list and show on partial product list

Comment: Can you use Draft product?